# Why is authorize() not working in production as it is in development enviroment?

Tags: php, laravel

When I upload my project to web server and when I try to login I get `403 error` but what confuses me is that it is working just fine in development enviroment. For example this is my controller function :

```
public function show($user){

$user = \App\User::find($user);
$this->authorize('view', $user->supplier);
return view("/Suppliers/supplier", compact('user'));}
```

and this is my policy:

```
public function view(User $user, Supplier $supplier)
{
    return $user->id === $supplier->user_id;
}
```

And it goes on for all `authorize()` functions. This is my first time deploying laravel app so any help is much appreciated.I am running laravel 8.0.1 version. And also I ran `php artisan cache:clear`
`php artisan route:clear` `php artisan config:clear`  and `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: maybe you are not actually logged in

Comment: When I go back and refresh the page I am logged in on index page. When I try again to go to the same page again the same error. It makes no sense to me at all. And ofcourse when I comment out  ```$this->authorize('view', $user->supplier);``` it is working normally

Comment: if the current authenticated user is not the user you are passing to `show` it will not be authorized ... looks ilke you need more details and debugging

Comment: I do realise that I need more debugging but what is bugging me is that it never happend in development enviroment

Comment: well we don't know your database and your data ... is the current authenticated user the same user with that 'id'?

Comment: Well I ran it with only one user who has a role of supplier, so yeah it is the same. So the user table is id 1 and supplier table is id 1 user_id 1. Everything else is empty

Comment: you can throw some `dump`s or `dd`s in there to see if it is even getting to the policy method ... you may want to dump those 2 ids that you are checking ... what database are you using? mysql? do remember that the primary key of the model is cast to an integer, it is possible that `user_id` is being returned as a string, which would make them `!==`

Comment: You are a legend , ```dd``` on user id gives 1 while ```dd``` on supplier user_id gives "1". Do you maybe know how to fix it ?

Comment: if you are using mysql, there was a `mysqlnd` (native driver) for PHP for these purposes, allowed the correct types to be used ... but i thought that might be the default being used now (perhaps not)

Comment: Yeah I am using mysql. I will check it out